# I have a second Inbox folder with a blue rightward arrow, it is empty and I can't delete it

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, inbox

My Outlook is connected using Exchange (on premises, not hosted). When I open Outlook a second folder named **Inbox** has appeared which I cannot delete. It is empty and when I view through the **Outlook Web App**, I don't see it.

Here is the view I get from the Folders Pane:

[image: View from Outlook Desktop Folders Pane]

The rightward facing blue arrow icon is for the Outbox folder. This second Inbox folder is indeed the Outbox, but how it came to be named Inbox I have no idea. When I send a message it appears briefly in this renamed Outbox folder.

Here is the view from Mail Pane:
[image: View from Mail Pane]

I have another machine on the same network, and when I opened Outlook on it (which I rarely do) it briefly showed the folder as Outbox and then flashed as it did Send/Receive and the folder was renamed Inbox. So it's not restricted to my local machine.

Another issue, that is potentially related, is I am now getting double reminder notifications:
[image: Double reminder notifications]

Comment: You can try renaming the .OST file so it gets rebuild and see if that solves it.

Comment: Nope. Started hacking and slashing... deleted pretty much in the `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\` folder. Still getting the duplicate inbox and reminders

Comment: What if you create a new outlook profile and setup the account? Its exchange so nothing is lost.

Comment: Nope, same issues with the new profile.

Comment: Btw, the item is not greyed out because there are no items to delete. Its greyed out because it is the default folder. The inbox cannot be removed. Given that the other folder can be removed, makes that other folder one that is not supposed to be there.

Comment: The Delete Folder context menu item is greyed out for both folders. I copied a message to my duplicate Inbox folder and the Delete All context menu item becomes available (now on both folders).

Comment: The only way I see this getting fixed is by doing a full export of your mailbox to PST, open the PST and ensure the duplicate folder is not present there, otherwise delete. Then ask your IT staff to remove the mailbox completely and recreate it, then import the PST back to your new account.

Comment: @KevinScharnhorst Please accept your own answer (after some time has passed, a day or so is customary). This will "close" the question and make it easier searchable for others with the same issue. Will also make it possible to link it to future questions (duplicates) about the same issue.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved:**
From Microsoft Docs on [incorrect folder names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/incorrect-folder-names)

Folder names are changed unexpectedly (for example, the **Inbox** folder and the **Outbox** folder are switched).

This issue may occur after *Exchange Server mailbox maintenance*. To resolve this issue, try Method 1 first:

1. Exit **Outlook**
2. Run `Outlook.exe /resetfolders`.
3. Run `Outlook.exe /resetfoldernames`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have an IMAP account in your data files via: 
 **File > Account Settings > Account Settings >
Data Files tab** [image: Screenshot]

- According to my search, if an IMAP account is set up in Outlook, it will automatically populate the [second inbox](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-365-two-inboxes-for-the-same-account/f070511b-34fe-401b-8b62-5b7da0080f54) with any duplicate emails
- Profile corruption may cause this problem, so try creating a new profile to see if it works: 
   **Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add exchange account**

*If you think my answer is helpful for you, please "Accept Answer" to help other people.*

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. IMAP is not set.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile? Does it work？

Comment: Creating a new profile doesn't help.

Comment: Exchange accounts generally don't use IMAP since an Exchange account is far superior when it comes to features, one of which is Exchange uses an offline `.pst` data file, whereas anything other than Exchange uses an online-only `.ost` data file _(`.pst` data files house all server & local data locally and are bi-directionally synced (If deleting an `.ost` file, all data not synced to the server is lost), whereas an `.ost` data file only stores an exact copy of what's on the server (no local data) and can only be synced with the server's data)_.